Как вставить шорткод в редактор Вордпресс?
На сайте выводится верстка через встроенный редактор (классический). В эту верстку нужно вставить слайдер который можно будет наполнять из админки (acf). Я попробовал добавить его через шорткод. Для этого зарегистрировал его в functions.php
add_shortcode( 'slider', 'slider_func' );

function slider_func(){
    $slider = get_template_part('slider');
    return $slider;
} 

но получилось немного не так как, я ожидал. Слайдер добавляется, но не в том месте, где я вставил шорткод. Он всегда оказывается перед кодом из редактора, независимо от того куда его вставить. Как это можно исправить? Или, может, есть более подходящее для этого решение?

Используйте ob_start() и ob_get_clean(), поведение вполне себе ожидаемо, так как get_template_part() выводит контент напрямую, как echo, например, а функция шорткода должна вернуть данные, а не выводить их, то есть return, а не echo.

Ок попробую. Спасибо

Как раз то что нужно! Спасибо!
